# Listen when a Dom element appears in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search bar icon  when you click it the search bar appears ▭

The code responsable for showning the search bar ▭ :

```
<ion-icon (click)="toggleSearchBar()" name="search"></ion-icon>
```

The Function:

```
toggleSearchBar() {
    this.shouldShowSearchBar = !this.shouldShowSearchBar;
    this.searchBarEl.setFocus();
}
```

But I have this problem:

1- I need to wrap `this.searchBarEl.setFocus();` inside `setTimeout` because the search bar is wrapped inside `*ngIf="shouldShowSearchBar"` which is not rendered so fast so if I don't wrap the method inside timeout it won't call because the dom element would have not appeared.

Can I listen when a Dom element appears in Angular?

Comment: If your search bar is contained in a different component, couldn't you simply call the focus on the input inside `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: everything in the same component and I use the Timeout hack for now, but so ugly

Comment: If you are really invested into going down this path, then you should have a look at the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: You could use `hidden` /  css `display:none` instead. This could be done with `*ngClass` or `*ngStyle`

Comment: @Igor I think this is a clever idea

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu do you think this will work with replacing elements totally? with *ngIf?

Comment: Yes, it should, but the css idea is not bad at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `*ngIf="shouldShowSearchBar"` to `[hidden]="!shouldShowSearchBar"` then the DOM will already contain the HTML element and you will not have to add `setTimeout` to your event handling code `toggleSearchBar`. You could also use `ngClass` or `ngStyle` in the same manner with the css `display: none`.

Comment: This really solving the problem thank you, I wish also if I could get an answer to my question.